# C#: How to transform String "[['x','x'],['x','x']]" into an Array without Split()ing?

Tags: c#, arrays

The string looks like a 2-D array:

```
[['a;b;c','d','e'],['a;b;c;d','h','k'], ... ]
```

But how do i evaluate it and transform it into 2D array in C# without using Split()?

Comment: By implementing `Split` yourself? Why wouldn't you use `Split`?

Comment: Is python an option? ;)  http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Oded I have the same thought every time I see this "how can I do x without using [obvious way to do x]" type of question...

Comment: @Oded Of course! It's homework!! That's why it's a weird question!

Comment: actually, it's not :P a string i'm ripping from a url is formatted like this.

Comment: @Steven - Split would not work as well with the strings inside the string carrying unexpected content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a programming problem and you are stuck, break it down into a simpler programming problem.  This answer will show you how to crudely parse using only C# string primitives just one "sub-array" of your string into a list.  That would be good progress and then you can start extending and improving the code.

```
var s = "['a;b;c','d','e']";
List<string> list = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
while (i < s.Length)
{
    char c = s[i++];
    if (c == '[')
    {
        while (i < s.Length)
        {
            c = s[i++];
            if (c == '\'')
            {
                int start = i;
                while (i < s.Length && s[i] != '\'')
                    i++;
                list.Add(s.Substring(start, i - start));
                i++;
            }
            if (i < s.Length && s[i] == ',')
                i++;
            if (i < s.Length && s[i] == ']')
            {
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

This produces as output:

```
a;b;c
d
e
```

It's not two-dimensional but I'm not going to write your whole program for you.  It's also puts it into a `List` instead of an array, but you have to do that anyway because you don't know how big it is.  This is what I mean by breaking the problem down into smaller parts that you can solve.

You can also improve the code by considerable error-checking for missing commas, etc.  But this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a JSON string. If it is, then use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) to deserialize the string into a `string[][]`